# Power BI Embedded mobile layout not working

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to get my app to support mobile layouts for reports. I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile), but the report isn't being laid out in the mobile portrait format. It's showing the master/default layout instead. The Power BI mobile app recognizes the report has the mobile layout and displays the report correctly. Below is my code. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function( $ ) {

            "use strict";

            var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

            var embedConfiguration = {
                type: 'report',
                embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=HIDE',
                tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                accessToken: 'HIDE',
                settings: {
                    filterPaneEnabled: false,
                    navContentPaneEnabled: false,
                    layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait,
                    localeSettings: {
                        language: 'en',
                        formatLocale: 'en'
                    }
                },

                id: 'HIDE',
            };

            var $container = $('#powerbi-embedded-40');

            var report = powerbi.embed($container.get(0), embedConfiguration);
        })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not be using latest powerbi-client. If you would press F12 in your browser you will see that there will be an error saying MobilePortrait is not recognized or is null.

Check this https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data sample solution from Microsoft itself, configure it and run with this property, it will work.

So, I would suggest you to update your packages.